# Create VM in ESXi using C# and the vSphere API .NET library

Tags: c#, .net, vmware, vsphere, esxi

How can I create a new VM in VMware vSphere ESXi using C# .NET?

I am using the vSphere API .NET Library VMware.Vim.dll from PowerCLI.
The following code explains the context.

```
using VMware.Vim;
public class VmCreator{
    VimClient Client = new VimClientImpl();

    public VmCreator(){
        Client.Connect("https://hostName/sdk");
        Client.Login("username", "password");

        // Create new VM goes here
    }
}
```

VMware themselves say that you can develop .NET applications for creating, customizing, or managing vSphere inventory objects using VMware.Vim.dll, so I thought it would be a good way to do it, but I cannot find any documentation at all.

Maybe there is a better/easier way to create ESXi VMs from a C# .NET project?

Answer (score 0):

If you use the vSphere Management SDK, there are already C# samples on creating a VM. That may be a better place to start and certainly has better documentation: http://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-5-5/topic/com.vmware.wssdk.pg.doc/PG_Appx_Sample_Overviews.23.3.html